# Adding nothing to a dictionary field

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, integer

I need to create a dictionary with one of the fields empty so that I can save integers into it later on. For example:

```
    users[x]  = ['forename': 'Terry', 'Surname': 'Tom', 'Score': ____]
```

The underscore section is where I don't know what to put.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect, you need `{}` braces instead of `[]` braces. Also, your question makes no sense; either set a default value or simply set the key when you have the integer you want to set.

Comment: I want 'Score' to be an array so that i can save it later on

Comment: Then use an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to add integers to the entry, set it to `0`. If you're just going to assign to it, then it doesn't matter what you put. A good choice would be `None`. In fact, if you are not going to use the key values for anything else, you don't need to put anything in at all.